# How to compute Gibbs energy in 2D image from a clear example

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have an interesting question about matrix. In Gibbs distribution, a Gibbs energy *U(x)* can be compute as

[image]

which is a sum of clique potentials Vc(x) over all possible cliques C (right image). A clique c is defined as a subset of sites in S (are neighborhood of x- blue color pixels are neighbor of yellow pixel in left figure) in which every pair of distinct sites are neighbors, except for single-site cliques

[image]

In which *V(x)* is computed as following:

[image]

My goal is how to compute *U(x)*. In my above example, *x={1,2}*. However, I have some stuck at pixel at corner of image that only has less than 8 neighbors (a pixel often has 8 neighbor pixels in normal case). To solve it, I added zeros at corner of edge by convolution image with an mask. But I think it maybe affect to U(x). From above definition, could you help me find U(x=1) and U(x=2) when i consider pixels at corner of image (gray color)? I tried to solve it by below solution but I think my solution is so long and I am not sure is whether correct or not.

This is what I do

```
Imlabel =[ 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1];
  mask=[ 0 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 0];
  Imlabel=conv2(Imlabel,mask); % To solve pixel in corner
  num_class=2; % x={1,2}
  beta=1;
  for label=1:num_class
    for i=2:size(Imlabel,1)-1
        for j=2:size(Imlabel,2)-1
            sum_V=0;
            %North, south, east and west neighbors
            if(label==Imlabel(i-1,j))   sum_V=sum_V+beta;
            else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
            if(label==Imlabel(i,j+1))   sum_V=sum_V+beta;
            else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
            if(label==Imlabel(i+1,j))   sum_V=sum_V+beta;
            else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
            if(label==Imlabel(i,j-1))   sum_V=sum_V+beta;
            else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
            %% Diagonal pixels
            if(label==Imlabel(i-1,j-1)) sum_V=sum_V+beta;
            else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
            if(label==Imlabel(i-1,j+1)) sum_V=sum_V+beta;
            else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
            if(label==Imlabel(i+1,j+1)) sum_V=sum_V+beta;
            else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
            if(label==Imlabel(i+1,j-1)) sum_V=sum_V+beta;
            else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
            %% Save
            U(i-1,j-1,label)=sum_V; %% Because Index is extended before
        end
    end    
end
```

Update: Normalization 
Currently, based on my understand at  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400273/what-does-it-means-of-normalization-term-of-gibbs-distribution). I computed normalized term as well as gibbs distribution as

```
P=zeros(size(U));
Z=sum(exp(-U),3);
for i=1:num_class
   P(:,:,i)=exp(-U(:,:,i))./Z;
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your explanation makes sense as well as the code.  However, you can totally get this vectorized by being smart about the kinds of functions you want to use.

For the interested readers, given your source code, what you want to do is the following (in pseudocode):

1. Create a matrix `U` that is `size(Imlabel,1) x size(Imlabel,2) x num_class` large.  Each slice of this matrix will determine which the Gibbs energy costs for the 8 neighbouring pixels at each coordinate `(i,j)` in this slice.
2. For each class label `x`...

   a. For each pixel in the image `(i,j)`...

   - Find those locations defined in an 8-pixel neighbourhood of `(i,j)` that are equal to `x` and set them to `beta`
   - Find those locations defined in an 8-pixel neighbourhood of `(i,j)` that are not equal to `x` and set them to `-beta`
   - Compute the sum of all of these `beta` and `-beta` values within this 8-pixel neighbourhood and set this at location `U(i,j,x)`

Therefore, what I would do is create a **3D matrix** of costs... let's call this `C`, where each slice `y` has the same dimensions as `size(Imlabel,1) x size(Imlabel,2)` but each location `(i,j)` in a slice will be `beta` if `Imlabel(i,j) == y` and `-beta` otherwise.  Once you do this, you can perform an N-D convolution of this matrix, but using a 2D kernel so that you can compute the summation of the 8-pixel neighbourhoods of each slice separately.

---

Today's magic menu consists of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`convn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) and a side-order of [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to sweeten the pot.

To get the cost matrix `C`, you can do this.  This is assuming `Imlabel` is **not padded with zeros** along the boundaries:

```
Imlabel =[ 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1];

C = double(bsxfun(@eq, Imlabel, permute(1:num_class, [1 3 2])));
C(C == 0) = -beta;
C(C == 1) = beta;
```

The `permute` function is used to create a single 3D vector that goes from 1 up to as many classes as you have defined.  The reason why this is required is because `bsxfun` does what is known as **broadcasting**.  What will happen in this case is given your matrix `Imlabel`, using the 3D vector will create a 3D cost matrix in conjunction with the `eq` or equals function.  Each slice of this cost matrix will give you the locations of where it is either equal to the label in question, or it isn't.

You can verify that what we have for the locations matrix that is output from `bsxfun` is correct:

```
>> C = double(bsxfun(@eq, Imlabel, permute(1:num_class, [1 3 2])))

C(:,:,1) =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1


C(:,:,2) =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

As you can see, for each slice, we can see which locations shared that label that is enumerated by that slice and those that don't share the same label.  Once we have these locations, we need to cast this to `double` so that we can modify this to be a cost matrix where `-beta` is a location that isn't equal to a label for a particular slice and `beta` is.  That is done by the two assignment statements after the `bsxfun` call.

Once you have this cost matrix, you can pad the boundaries like you did before, but make sure that the boundaries are set to a cost of `-beta` as you have done in your code:

```
mask = zeros(3,3); mask(2,2) = 1;
Cpad = convn(C, mask);
Cpad(Cpad == 0) = -beta;
```

The first line of code denotes the `[0 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0]` mask that you defined in your code.  Now to pad each slice independently to have a border of zeroes, we can use `convn` to help us do that.

---

Now that we have that set up, all you have to do is perform the calculation of Gibbs' energy independently per slice:

```
mask2 = ones(3,3); mask2(2,2) = 0;
out = convn(Cpad, mask2, 'valid');
```

The first line of code denotes a mask where every value is 1 except for the middle, which is 0 and it is a 3 x 3 mask.  The reason why you want to do this is because this replaces the `if/else` statements in your double `for` loop logic.  What you are doing is essentially a **convolution** where you are adding up all of the 8 neighbours except for the middle itself.  This can be accomplished by using a mask that has all 1s except for the central pixel and you set that to 0.

Next, we use `convn` to compute the Gibbs' energy per slice independently, but using the `'valid'` flag so that we can remove the zero-padded border we included at the beginning.

Now, if you take a look at `out`, it compares with what you have with `U`, but there is a slight shift because of the way you are indexing into `U`.  Nevertheless, with the above output of `out`, you can verify that what we have is correct and this will handle the border cases nicely:

```
>> out

out(:,:,1) =

    -2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2    -2
     2     8     8     8     8     8     6     6     6     2
     2     8     8     8     8     8     6     8     6     2
     2     6     4     2     4     6     6     6     6     2
     2     4     2     0     4     6     8     8     8     2
     2     4     2     0     2     6     8     6     6     0
     2     6     4     4     6     8     8     6     8     0
     2     8     8     8     8     8     8     6     6     0
    -2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2    -2


out(:,:,2) =

    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8
    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -6    -6    -6    -8
    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -6    -8    -6    -8
    -8    -6    -4    -2    -4    -6    -6    -6    -6    -8
    -8    -4    -2     0    -4    -6    -8    -8    -8    -8
    -8    -4    -2     0    -2    -6    -8    -6    -6    -6
    -8    -6    -4    -4    -6    -8    -8    -6    -8    -6
    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -6    -6    -6
    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8    -8
```

For example, if we took a look at the top left corner of the first slice, we see that the east, south and south east corners have the same label of 1, and so since `beta = 1`, our sum would be 3, but then there are the other 5 directions that we didn't consider, and in your code, you set those to `-beta` and so `3 - 5 = -2`.

Let's also take a look at the 6th row, 4th column and let's take a look at the second label or slice.  This means that any cardinal directions that are equal to label 2, we should sum these with `beta / 1` while anything that isn't equal to label 2 is `-beta / -1`.  As you can see, there are exactly 4 labels of 1 and 4 labels of 2, and so these should cancel out and give us a 0.

You can verify that what we did for all of the other locations in this matrix result in the right calculations.

The full code is simply:

```
Imlabel =[ 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1];

C = double(bsxfun(@eq, Imlabel, permute(1:num_class, [1 3 2])));
C(C == 0) = -beta;
C(C == 1) = beta;

mask = zeros(3,3); mask(2,2) = 1;
Cpad = convn(C, mask);
Cpad(Cpad == 0) = -beta;

mask2 = ones(3,3); mask2(2,2) = 0;
out = convn(Cpad, mask2, 'valid');
```

---

In the case of timing, we can check to see how fast the above approach is compared to your original loop code.  I used [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) to help facilitate that.

Here's the script I set up that sets up all of the relevant variables, and measures the time taken with your code and mine:

```
function test_clique_timing

% Setup
Imlabel_orig =[ 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1;
           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1];
num_class=2; % x={1,2}
beta = 1;

    function test_orig
        mask=[ 0 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 0];
        Imlabel=conv2(Imlabel_orig,mask); % To solve pixel in corner
        beta=1;
        for label=1:num_class
            for i=2:size(Imlabel,1)-1
                for j=2:size(Imlabel,2)-1
                    sum_V=0;
                    %North, south, east and west neighbors
                    if(label==Imlabel(i-1,j))   sum_V=sum_V+beta;
                    else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
                    if(label==Imlabel(i,j+1))   sum_V=sum_V+beta;
                    else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
                    if(label==Imlabel(i+1,j))   sum_V=sum_V+beta;
                    else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
                    if(label==Imlabel(i,j-1))   sum_V=sum_V+beta;
                    else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
                    %% Diagonal pixels
                    if(label==Imlabel(i-1,j-1)) sum_V=sum_V+beta;
                    else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
                    if(label==Imlabel(i-1,j+1)) sum_V=sum_V+beta;
                    else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
                    if(label==Imlabel(i+1,j+1)) sum_V=sum_V+beta;
                    else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
                    if(label==Imlabel(i+1,j-1)) sum_V=sum_V+beta;
                    else sum_V=sum_V-beta;end
                    %% Save
                    U(i-1,j-1,label)=sum_V; %% Because Index is extended before
                end
            end
        end
    end

    function test_conv
        C = double(bsxfun(@eq, Imlabel_orig, permute(1:num_class, [1 3 2])));
        C(C == 0) = -beta;
        C(C == 1) = beta;

        mask = zeros(3,3); mask(2,2) = 1;
        Cpad = convn(C, mask);
        Cpad(Cpad == 0) = -beta;

        mask2 = ones(3,3); mask2(2,2) = 0;
        out = convn(Cpad, mask2, 'valid');
    end

time1 = timeit(@test_orig);
time2 = timeit(@test_conv);

fprintf('Loop code time: %f seconds\n', time1);
fprintf('Vectorized code time: %f seconds\n', time2);
fprintf('Speedup factor: %f', time1/time2);

end
```

Running the above script, I get these for times:

```
Loop code time: 0.000049 seconds
Vectorized code time: 0.000060 seconds
Speedup factor: 0.816667
```

This is done in seconds and I did this using MATLAB R2013a under Mac OS Mavericks 10.10.5.  The speedup doesn't look that great. In fact it's a factor less than 1, which is terrible.  However, what you have shown is such a small dataset.  We should try with a larger dataset and see if this still holds.  Let's make the matrix 2500 x 2500, with 10 class labels.  I'm going to replace the `Imlabel` matrix with:

```
rng(123); %// Set seed for reproducibility
num_class = 10;
Imlabel_orig = randi(10,2500,2500);
```

This produces random integers from 1 to 10 in a 2500 x 2500 matrix.  Doing this and running the code again gives:

```
Loop code time: 17.553669 seconds
Vectorized code time: 3.321950 seconds
Speedup factor: 5.284146
```

Yeah... that's much better.  On the 2500 x 2500 matrix of 10 labels, it took roughly 17.5 seconds to compute, whereas the the vectorized code with `bsxfun / convn / permute` outperforms your original loop code by a factor of almost 5.2x.

---

As for the normalization term to factor into your Gibbs' energy calculation, you currently have this:

```
P=zeros(size(U));
Z=sum(exp(-U),3);
for i=1:num_class
   P(:,:,i)=exp(-U(:,:,i))./Z;
end
```

If you take advantage of `bsxfun`, you can simply do this:

```
Z = sum(exp(-out),3)); %// out is U in my code
P = bsxfun(@rdivide, exp(-out), Z);
```

This achieves the same thing your code does.  For each slice in `P`, we find the `exp` and negate the slice as input, and divide each term by `Z`.  For `bsxfun`, the `Z` matrix gets replicated for as many slices as there are in `out` and does the element-wise division much like the loop code does.

Comment: It is very fast and clearly understand. I would like say thank for your great code. If I want to normalized the U(x) by divide it by Z term  (e.q 4.5) in the paper http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~acthomas/724/Geman.pdf  Is it possible to do it? Thanks. If you need create a new question. I will make it

Comment: @user3051460 So you want to normalize each 8-pixel summation?  You simply have to scale the mask.  Can you confirm before I edit my post?

Comment: I think no. the explanation of normalization may be i post at here . But i am not sure about my understand of Z term. Let see it at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400273/what-does-it-means-of-normalization-term-of-gibbs-distribution

Comment: @user3051460 - I will have a look very soon.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3051460 - Yes, that normalization term is quite easy to do vectorized.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: @user3051460 - Have a look.

Comment: Yes. Do you think my understand about that normalize term correct? I am confusing sum over x that mean sum of x=1 and sum of x=2 or sum of all pixel in each domain x=1 and x=2.

Comment: @user3051460 - I honestly don't know.  I haven't really dealt with MRFs before and I currently don't have the time to read through the paper to verify if your interpretation is correct.  You'll have to wait until when I have free time if you'd like me to verify.