# How to speed up my code [includes example] in Matlab?

Tags: algorithm, performance, matlab, image-processing

I want to speed up my code. Currently, I used if statement to do it. However, it can be make faster code if we use the [convolution way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056577/how-to-compute-gibbs-energy-in-2d-image-from-a-clear-example). However, it only works for simple case (as pairwise neighborhood). Let us define my issue.

I have a matrix `I=[1 1 1;2 2 2;2 2 1]` which has two label `{1,2}`. I added the padding as its right side. For each pixel in the `I`, we can defined a pairwise or triple of neighborhood. We will check base on a rule "if these neighborhood value has same class with the pixel, then set a cost value equal `-beta`, otherwise set the cost equal `beta`".

[image]

For example, let consider the yellow pixel in above figure. Its label is 2. We need to compute total of  cost value over possible neighborhood case as show in rightmost side. The value of interesting pixels will be set from label {1,2}. In above figure. I just show first case which set the yellow pixel equals 1. We can have same figure, but set yellow pixel is 2 for next case. My task is that compute the cost function base on the above rule.

This is my code. However, it use if statement. It is so slow. Could you help me to speed up it? I tried to use convolution way but I have no idea how to define a mask for triple of neighborhood. Thank all

```
function U=compute_gibbs(Imlabel,beta,num_class)
num_class=2;
Imlabel=[1 1 1;2 2 2;2 2 1]
beta=1;
U=zeros([size(Imlabel) num_class]);
Imlabel = padarray(Imlabel,[1 1],'replicate','both');
[row,col] = size(Imlabel);
for ii = 2:row-1        
    for jj = 2:col-1
        for l = 1:num_class
            U(ii-1,jj-1,l)=GibbsEnergy(Imlabel,ii,jj,l,beta);
        end
    end
end
function energy = GibbsEnergy(img,i,j,label,beta)
    % img is the labeled image
    energy = 0;
    if (label == img(i,j)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end        
    % North, south, east and west
    if (label == img(i-1,j)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
    if (label == img(i,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
    if (label == img(i+1,j)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
    if (label == img(i,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
    % diagonal elements
    if (label == img(i-1,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
    if (label == img(i-1,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
    if (label == img(i+1,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
    if (label == img(i+1,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
     %% Triangle elements
    % Case a 
    if(label==img(i-1,j)&label==img(i-1,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 
    if(label==img(i,j-1)&label==img(i+1 ,j)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
    if(label==img(i,j+1)&&label==img(i+1 ,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 
    % Case b 
    if(label==img(i-1,j-1)&label==img(i,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end     
     if(label==img(i-1,j)&label==img(i ,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end  
     if(label==img(i+1,j)&label==img(i+1,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
         else energy = energy+beta;end  
    % Case c   
    if(label==img(i,j-1)&label==img(i+1,j-1)) energy = energy-beta;
         else energy = energy+beta;end  
    if(label==img(i+1,j)&label==img(i,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
         else energy = energy+beta;end  
    if(label==img(i-1 ,j)&label==img(i-1,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 
    % Case d 
    if(label==img(i,j-1)&label==img(i-1,j)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 
    if(label==img(i-1 ,j+1)&label==img(i,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 
     if(label==img(i+1,j-1)&label==img(i+1 ,j)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 

    %% Rectangular
    if(label==img(i-1,j-1)&label==img(i,j-1)&label==img(i-1 ,j)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 
    if(label==img(i,j-1)&label==img(i+1,j-1)&label==img(i+1 ,j)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 
     if(label==img(i+1,j)&label==img(i +1 ,j+1)&label==img(i,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end 
     if(label==img(i-1,j)&label==img(i-1,j+1)&label==img(i ,j+1)) energy = energy-beta;
        else energy = energy+beta;end
```

This is one faster way. But it only works for simple case (pairwise neighborhood-first row), while my case includes single, triple...neighborhood

```
C = double(bsxfun(@eq, Imlabel, permute(1:num_class, [1 3 2])));
C(C == 0) = 0;
C(C == 1) = beta;
%% Replace if statement
mask = zeros(3,3); mask(2,2) = 1;
Cpad = convn(C, mask);
Cpad(Cpad == 0) = 0;

mask2 = ones(3,3); mask2(2,2) = 0;
energy = convn(Cpad, mask2, 'valid');
```

Comment: Why dont you create masks and then multiply them?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Do you think it will be more faster?

Comment: Yes. **MAT**trix **LAB**oratory is desinged to be fastest with matrices

Comment: Could you implement it and I would like to compare with original code about computational time? Thanks

Comment: HAhahahaha. **NO**. have you seen how long is your code?

Comment: It about 0.004189 seconds. for 3x3 matrix. But it is very slow for larger matrix

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I used a mask =[1 1 1;1 0 1; 1 1 1] and conv with image to replace if statements. However, it is only for east, south, ...and diagonal -1 neighbor pixel. For two neighbor pixels-triangle case, I have no idea about mask. What do you think about that?

Comment: I'm confused by your first example, "Cost=-beta because 1~=2(its label)". How did you determine that the label of `1` is `2`?

Comment: It means the label of yellow pixel in original image. Let see it in leftmost side.

Comment: And in other case, we will want to compute cost of label 1. Thus, we will replace 1 in to the pixel (yellow pixel). On same manner, we will put 2 in the pixel when we compute cost of label 2

Comment: Okay, so the diagram on the right is the case when you're searching for matches to `label 1`, then you want to search for matches to `label 2` in the same neighborhood. Got it.

Comment: The above diagram only show for label=1. It is right. And I shown my code above. For label=2, it has same way. I implemented the algorithm by matlab code. But it is so slow. I would like to improve/speed up this code by convolution/or any way in MATLAB?

Comment: @user8430 "But it is very slow for larger matrix"... how large are the matrices you want to work with and how long is your current implementation taking?

Comment: The matrix means the 'I' matrix. The matrix maybe 1000x1000 or the above function can call many time. Hence, I want to speed up it. Currently, for small matrix, I spend 0.004189  sec. But if i use convolution way, it can faster 5~10 times

Comment: That doesn't tell me how fast you want the calculations on the 1000x1000 matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106177/discussion-between-user8430-and-beaker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my attempts at this. I can't really tell if either one going to be faster for you because I'm using Octave rather than MATLAB and the timings can be *wildly* different. For instance, `for` loops still take forever in Octave. You'll have to test them out and see how they compare.

## Matrix Multiplication

As [@AnderBiguri notes in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946519/how-to-speed-up-my-code-includes-example-in-matlab#comment59549803_35946519), one way to go is to use matrix multiplication. If you take a 3x3 neighborhood, say

```
nbr = [0 0 0;
       1 0 0;
       1 1 0];
```

and you want to know if the top-left element is a `1`, you can perform element-wise multiplication by the mask

```
mask = [1 0 0;
        0 0 0;
        0 0 0];

result = sum(mask .* nbr);
```

(I'm taking a shortcut here by assuming that the neighborhood is a binary matrix. When I get to the actual code, I'll simply use `nbr == current_class` to make this so.)

If the result has the same number of `1` elements as the mask, then you've got a match. In this case, the element-wise multiplication of these two is all zeros, so no match.

Rather than element-wise multiplication followed by summing the elements of the result, we can just make `nbr` and `mask` into vectors and use vector multiplication:

```
m = mask(:).';
n = nbr(:);
result = m * n;
```

This will give you the same value as the previous result. If you have a matrix of masks, you can multiply it by the neighborhood vector and get all of the results at once. So the first step is to generate the 25 mask vectors:

```
masks = [
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0;
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0;
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0;
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1;
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0;
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0;
   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0;
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0;
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1;
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1;
   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0;
   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0;
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0;
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0;
   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0;
   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0;
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1;
   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0];
```

Now when you multiply `masks` by the neighborhood, you get all of the results at once. Then you compare the result to the sums of the rows of `masks` to see which ones match.

```
result = masks * n;
matches = sum(masks, 2) == result;
match_count = sum(matches);
```

For each match, we subtract `beta` from the energy. For each non-match, we add `beta`, so

```
possible_matches = 25; %// the number of neighborhood types
energy = -beta * match_count + beta * (possible_matches - match_count);
```

Now all we have to do is to figure out how to get all of the 3x3 neighborhoods out of our image. Fortunately, MATLAB has the [im2col](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) function which does just this. Even better, it only takes the valid neighborhoods of the image, so if it's already padded, you're ready to go.

```
function G = gibbs(img, beta, classcount)

   masks = [
      0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0;
      0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0;
      0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1;
      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1;
      0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0;
      0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0;
      0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0;
      1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1;
      0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0];

   [m,n] = size(img);
   possible_matches = size(masks, 1);
   Imlabel = padarray(img, [1 1], 'replicate', 'both');

   col_label = im2col(Imlabel, [3 3], 'sliding');
   target = repmat(sum(masks, 2), [1, m*n]);

   for ii = 1:classcount
      found = masks*(col_label == ii);
      match_count = sum(found == target, 1);
      energy = -beta * match_count + beta*(possible_matches - match_count);
      G(:,:,ii) = reshape(energy, m, n);
   end

end
```

---

## Look-Up Table

If you look at the Matrix Multiplication solution, it's multiplying the neighborhood of each pixel by the 25 masks. For a 1000 x 1000 image, that's `1000 x 1000 x 25 x 9 = 225M` multiplications. But there are only `512` (2^9) possible neighbor configurations. So if we figure out what those 512 configurations are, multiply them by the masks, and sum up the matches, we've got a 512-element look-up table and all we have to do for each neighborhood in the image is calculate its index. Here's how to create the look-up table using `masks` from above:

```
possible_neighborhoods = de2bi(0:511, 9).';
found = masks * possible_neighborhoods;
target = repmat(sum(masks, 2), [1, size(found, 2)]);
LUT = sum(found == target, 1);
```

This is pretty much what we were doing in each loop before, but we're doing it for all possible neighborhoods, which is equivalent to all of the bit patterns for the numbers `0:511`.

Now, instead of a binary vector for each pixel that we multiply by the masks, we want a decimal index into the look-up table. For that we can use `conv2` with a kernel that effectively does a binary-to-decimal conversion:

```
k = [1   8   64;
     2  16  128;
     4  32  256];

or

k = [2^0  2^3  2^6
     2^1  2^4  2^7
     2^2  2^5  2^8];
```

This will give us values of `0:511` for each pixel, so we add one to get to `1:512` and use that as an index into the look-up table. Here's the full code:

```
function G = gibbs2(img, beta, classcount)

   masks = [
      0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0;
      0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0;
      0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1;
      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1;
      0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0;
      0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0;
      0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0;
      1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1;
      0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0];

   [m,n] = size(img);
   possible_matches = size(masks, 1);
   possible_neighborhoods = de2bi(0:511, 9).';   %'
   found = masks * possible_neighborhoods;
   target = repmat(sum(masks, 2), [1, size(found, 2)]);
   LUT = sum(found == target, 1);
   
   k = [1   8   64;
        2  16  128;
        4  32  256];
        
   Imlabel = padarray(img, [1 1], 'replicate', 'both');

   for ii = 1:classcount
      filterImage = conv2(double(Imlabel == ii), k, 'valid');
      matchImg = LUT(filterImage + 1);
      G(:,:,ii) = -beta * matchImg + beta * (possible_matches - matchImg);
   end
   
end
```

Since we're doing a lot fewer multiplications for a 1000x1000 image, this approach is about 7x faster than the Matrix Multiplication method on my machine using Octave.

Comment: Really amazing. I am measuring the performance. I will let you know later. I found a minor bug in second code in matlab. the line Imlabel == ii (in conv2(Imlabel == ii,...)) need to convert to double as double(Imlabel == ii).

Comment: Yes, apparently MATLAB wants the argument to `conv2` to be either single or double. I'll go ahead and change that.

Comment: Thank beaker. I spend time to understand and measure your way.  As my check in MATLAB, the your first way speeds up 2 times and second way speeds up 13 times for 500x500 size of matrix with 4 classes, comparison with my way. It is really good approach. I understood the first way. However, I still not understand about second way. Why has 2^9 possible neighbor, not 2^10? How many  possible neighbor configurations of 4 neighborhood (Is it 2^2?))?

Comment: It's 2^9 because there are 9 cells in the neighborhood and each cell is binary (it either matches the class, or it doesn't). For 4-connected neighborhood it would be 2^5 because you've got the center cell and its 4 neighbors.

Comment: Could we chat together at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106177/discussion-between-user8430-and-beaker